# Matrix raised to a power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find $A^n$ for $n = 1,2,...$. Does $A^n$ tend to a limit? $$A= \begin{pmatrix} 4/5 & 2/5 \\ 1/5 & 3/5 \end{pmatrix}$$

I found the eigenvalues $\lambda=1,2/5$ and the eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\  1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\  1\end{pmatrix}$

I know that $A= \begin{pmatrix} -1/3 & 2/3 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2/5 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Also $A^n = P^{-1}B^nP=P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 2/5^n & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}P$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Well, what happens when $n$ goes to infinity? $P$ doesn't depend on $n$ but the diagonal matrix does, and it's limit is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done.

It remains to find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}A^n$, which is
$$
A^n= \begin{pmatrix} -1/3 & 2/3 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} (2/5)^n & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\to
\begin{pmatrix} -1/3 & 2/3 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 2/3 & 2/3 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 \end{pmatrix}.
$$